# How to find numbers and alphabets in images and blur them(mask them)?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract

I have to blur the identification number without doing a hard code. I want to find the identification number on its own and blur that number for example

[image: scanned image]

In this image I need to blur the Account number i.e ABCDE1234F. This is the code that I have done so far:

```
# pylint: disable=import-error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import easyocr
from pylab import rcParams
from IPython.display import Image
# size of image
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 8, 16
#language to read
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
#read imgae
##image = cv2.imread('aadhar.jpg')
image = cv2.imread('pancard.jpg')
# saved pre trained model in variable called reader and extract text using readtext  and then saved the output in variable called output
##output = reader.readtext('aadhar.jpg')
output = reader.readtext('pancard.jpg')
print(output)
# extracted the word which we need to blur and saved the it in the variable name cord
##cord = output[6][0]
cord = output[8][0]
print(cord)
# catched up the min and max the cordinates of bounding box
x_min, y_min = [int(min(idx)) for idx in zip(*cord)]
x_max, y_max = [int(max(idx)) for idx in zip(*cord)]
print(x_min)
print(y_min)
print(x_max)
print(y_max)

# Create ROI coordinates(region of interest)
topLeft = (x_min, y_min)
bottomRight = (x_max, y_max)
x, y = topLeft[0], topLeft[1]
w, h = bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0], bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1]

# Grab ROI with Numpy slicing and blur
ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(ROI, (51,51), 0)

# Insert ROI back into image
image[y:y+h, x:x+w] = blur

#cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I hard code the coordinates of the number which I need to blur. I am able to identify the region but I am not sure how to identify the number on its own and blur the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re


def downloadImage(URL):
    """Downloads the image on the URL, and convers to cv2 RGB format"""
    from io import BytesIO
    from PIL import Image as PIL_Image
    import requests

    response = requests.get(URL)
    image = PIL_Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


URL = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYznL.jpg"

image =downloadImage(URL)

import easyocr

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
output = reader.readtext(image)

#identify the PAN number
#regex from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-validate-pan-card-number-using-regular-expression/
regex = "[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}"

for out in output:
    if re.match(regex, out[1]):
        print(out)
        PAN=out
        break

# extracted the word which we need to blur and saved the it in the variable name cord
##cord = output[6][0]
cord = PAN[0]
print(cord)
# catched up the min and max the cordinates of bounding box
x_min, y_min = [int(min(idx)) for idx in zip(*cord)]
x_max, y_max = [int(max(idx)) for idx in zip(*cord)]
print(x_min)
print(y_min)
print(x_max)
print(y_max)

# Create ROI coordinates(region of interest)
topLeft = (x_min, y_min)
bottomRight = (x_max, y_max)
x, y = topLeft[0], topLeft[1]
w, h = bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0], bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1]

# Grab ROI with Numpy slicing and blur
ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(ROI, (51,51), 0)

# Insert ROI back into image
image[y:y+h, x:x+w] = blur

#cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Colim for the help. I have one more question instead of using URL's can we read the image. I tried reading the image using this code "image = cv2.imread('pancard.jpg')" but I am getting some errors

Comment: Instead of `image =downloadImage(URL)` use `image = cv2.imread('pancard.jpg')`. Which errors do you get?

Comment: Now it's working but I don't want to download the image using the URL instead I want to use the image which is on my desktop and read it. How can I do that? Can you please help me with the same?

Comment: You do not need to download any image. delete the code downloalding the image

Comment: I want to blur one more image how can i get the url for the same?

Comment: If you don't know how to open an image, google it, or ask another question. The code you posted has the code to open an image.

Comment: This code gives me errors when I use another sample of PAC cards. It says
````File "/Users/nikmac/Desktop/pan card /e7.py", line 36, in <module>
    cord = PAN[0]
NameError: name 'PAN' is not defined````

Comment: I can't do anything with a path to an image in your computer. PAN is defined when a match is found inside the For loop, so it must mean that the OCR failed to detect the text. You should ask a question, posting the image, with the problem being that the text is not detected, so other people can diagnose why the text is not detected, and recommend fixes.

Comment: Just wanna ask one more thing what is this ````if re.match(regex, out[1]):````
Can you please tell me!

Comment: That is a regular expression. It detects the PAN text pattern in `regex = "[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}"`, which means 5 letters, followed by 4 numbers, ended with one letter. The `for` loop checks in all the text detected by EasyOCR, until it finds one text matching the PAN pattern, which is the number that you want to blur.